# What is the best way to assign nil to a default association?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

So if I have a factory such as this (address is another factory) and I want to create a test that creates a person with no address

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    address
    first        { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last         { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end
end
```

I would expect the following to work (but doesn't):

`create(:person, address: nil)`

What is the best way to set this up properly?

Comment: Passing it nil should work... you don't have any after-create calls or anything that might be setting the address?

Comment: Yeah it does work.  Stupid mistake, my model had `validates_numericality_of :address_id, only_integer: true` and should have had: `validates_numericality_of :address_id, only_integer: true, allow_blank: true`  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Easy lesson to stumble in to :]